# Creating Ant classpath out of project names

Tags: ant, classpath

In an ant build script I have a list of projects we are depending on. I need to create a classpath for compilation.

I have:

```
included.projects=ProjectA, ProjectB
```

and I need:

```
included.project.classpath=../ProjectA/bin, ../ProjectB/bin
```

current code:

```
<echo message="${included.projects}" />

<pathconvert property="included.projects.classpath" dirsep="," >
      <map from="" to="../"/>
        <path location="${included.projects}"/>
    </pathconvert>

<echo message="${included.projects.classpath}" />

<javac srcdir="${src.dir}" destdir="${build.dir}" includeantruntime="false" source="1.6">
    <classpath>
        <pathelement path="${classpath}" />
        <dirset includes="${included.projects.classpath}" />
    </classpath>
</javac>
```

I've tried it with explicit declaration too, but didn't work:

```
<path id="modules.classpath"> 
  <fileset dir="../ModuleA/bin" /> 
  <fileset dir="../ModuleB/bin"/> 
</path> 
<path id="libraries.classpath"> 
  <fileset dir="lib" includes="*.jar"/> 
</path> 
<javac srcdir="${src.dir}" destdir="${build.dir}" includeantruntime="false" source="1.6"> 
   <classpath refid="libraries.classpath" /> 
   <classpath refid="modules.classpath" /> 
</javac>
```

I'm curious, what is the problem with explicit declaration code, and is it possible to solve with the comma-separated-string to classpath solution.

Comment: It is working when using `<path id="modules.classpath">
   <pathelement path="../ModuleA/bin" /> ...`

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be simpler to explicity declare the classpath at the top of your build as follows:

```
<path id="compile.path">
   <fileset dir="../ProjectA/bin" includes="*.jar"/>
   <fileset dir="../ProjectB/bin" includes="*.jar"/>
</path>
```

Used as follows:

```
<javac srcdir="${src.dir}" destdir="${build.dir}" includeantruntime="false" source="1.6">
    <classpath>
        <path refid="compile.path"/>
        <pathelement path="${classpath}" />
    </classpath>
</javac>
```

Note:

- I read your question again and just realised that you're not using jar files built by the other projects, are you? .... Not a great idea....

Comment: With your solution I would need to to put the big 'compile.path' declaration in all my build.xml but I would like to use a commmon build.xml. About Note: sure... why would I? I know it is a kind of standard, but I don't see the point in my case: It's a small project with 5-10 modules, and everything is constantly changing.  This way I can save a compression, a copy-to-repository and decompression.